# Pygame unresponsive display

Tags: python, pygame

So I am attempting to create the foundation for a basic 2D python game with X and Y movement using a sprite.

However the display is unresposive despite the code here attempting to `screen.fill` and `screen.blit`

```
playerX = 50
playerY = 50
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")
width, height = 64*8, 64*8
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
screen.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))
```

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal, typical PyGame application

- has a game loop
- has to handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- has to update the [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) whuch represents the display respectively window, by either [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) or [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update).

See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

See also [Python Pygame Introduction](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html)

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

playerX = 50
playerY = 50
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")
width, height = 64*8, 64*8
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# main application loop
run = True
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # draw the scene   
    screen.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: This works great and thank you for the explanation, the coding continues!