# What is the quickest way to draw multiple circles in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I am making an agario clone for a project and I was wondering what the quickest way to draw many dots in pygame.

```
from pygame import *
import random as rd 

x = rd.randint(100, 700)
y = rd.randint(100, 500)


# I would like to draw about 50 dots of this type. 
dot = draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 5)
```

Comment: I would use a `for` loop. Is there a concern about performance?

Comment: I don't have any concerns about performance at the moment.

Comment: Also how exactly would it work? Would I just define the dot variable in the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some basic code to draw circles using pygame:

```
import pygame as pg
import random as rd 

pg.init()  # initialize pygame  
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500,500))  # create main screen

for ctr in range(25):  # 25 circles
    x = rd.randint(50, 450)
    y = rd.randint(50, 450)
   
    # I would like to draw about 50 dots of this type. 
    dot = pg.draw.circle(screen, (100, 200, 100), (x, y), 15)
    pg.display.update()  # update screen
    
while True:  # main pygame loop, always include this
    for event in pg.event.get(): # required for OS events
      if event.type == pg.QUIT:  # user closed window
         pg.quit()
```

Output

[image: Circles]

Answer (score 1):

Any easy way to do this to use a simple python ["for" loop with a "range"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop):

As the loop iterates, it executes the content of the loop body, with the variable `i` incrementing from 0 to *N-1* (i.e. 49).  The variable `i` could be any valid variable name, but for simple numbered loops, `i`, `j` & `k` are commonly used.

```
from pygame import *
import random as rd 

# Draw 50 dots 
for i in range( 0, 50 ):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    dot = draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a class for dots:

```
class Dot():
    SIZE = 5
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), Dot.SIZE)
```

Then I made an array and generate `NUMBER_OF_DOTS` like this:

```
dots = []

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DOTS):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    dots.append(Dot(x,y))
```

and in the `while` loop and redraw after filling the whole scene by white color:

while True:
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
...
for dot in dots:
dot.draw()

The whole source:

```
from pygame import *
import random as rd

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
NUMBER_OF_DOTS = 300

class Dot():
    SIZE = 5
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = random_color()

    def draw(self):
        draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), Dot.SIZE)
    
def random_color():
    r = rd.randint(0, 255)
    g = rd.randint(0, 255)
    b = rd.randint(0, 255)
    return (r, g, b)


init()
screen = display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

dots = []

# generate random dots all over the screen
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DOTS):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    dots.append(Dot(x,y))


# main while loop
while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    for dot in dots:
        dot.draw()


    display.update()
    time.delay(1) # Speed down
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the same circles continuously in the main application loop, then you've to generate a list of random positions:

```py
import pygame as pg
import random as rd 

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))

cpts = []
for i in range(25):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    cpts.append((x, y))
    
run = True
while run: 
    for event in pg.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pg.QUIT: 
            run = False

    for cpt in cpts: 
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), cpt, 15)
    pg.display.update()
```

See the answer to [Pygame unresponsive display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540062/pygame-unresponsive-display/63540113?noredirect=1) for a minimum pygame application.